# Mailings -> New Mailing page freeze

Tags: wordpress, mailing

I'm running civicrm 5.27.2 on wordpress.

When I click into the new mailing in the mailings menu, the page freezes. The console yields this error:

```
angular-modules.fb2f4d770923a3db9400b2a235e84801.js:1095 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'contextMenu' of undefined
at angular-modules.fb2f4d770923a3db9400b2a235e84801.js:1095
at angular-modules.fb2f4d770923a3db9400b2a235e84801.js:1097

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.11%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DcrmApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A6%3A426%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A25%3A235%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A24%3A282)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A25%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A40%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A7%3A371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A39%3A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A43%3A381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A21%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Gc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcivicrm%2Fcivicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3DRHCn5%3A21%3A332)
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4692
at q (angular.js:325)
at g (angular.js:4653)
at fb (angular.js:4575)
at c (angular.js:1809)
at Gc (angular.js:1830)
at se (angular.js:1715)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:32616)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Sounds like a conflict or version mismatch. Are you using Mosaico for new mailings or is from a new "traditional" mailing? I am on Wordpress 5.4.2 with the following:

CiviCRM 5.27.3
Mosaico 2.4.1592820024
FlexMailer 1.1.1
Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.2
Shoreditch 1.0.0-beta.1

I also rely heavily on Christian Wach's "CiviCRM Admin Utilities" plugin for Wordpress (version 0.7.3).

Comment: Perhaps confirm that you have already tried clearing civi caches, and if not, give it a go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I remember just that I had to make some edit for the debugging symbols, but can not find my notes about this. It was related to the angular modules